# Android Development: Read outlook emails in own app activity

Tags: java, android, outlook

I am relatively new to android, and I would like to know if it is possible to read outlook emails in an activity/fragment in my own app I am developping. 
If yes, can you please provide me with information/examples of what would i need to enable this feature in my application and any working example/code for reading emails in an activity/fragment.

Thank you in advance for your assistance,

Answer (score 2):

U can use EWS protocol to read outlook mails. 
U can download EWS java api from this link http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi
You can get sample  programs using from this link.http://luckyacademy.blogspot.in/2012/02/java-client-exchange-web-services-ews.html

Comment: Do I need to have some sort of access priviledge to read emails from an exchange server (In a  Company)?If so, is there a way to access those emails and how?. Thank you in advance, I am not familiar this subject.

Comment: You should have a mail account in the exchange server and the credentials for that.

Comment: EWS Java API has issues with Android API v23 and above